# How to subcribe tf transform from map to odom by gmapping into odom to baselink?

Tags: navigation, odometry, transform, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have an odometry obtained from encoders but it is not accurate enough. In long periods, the error accumulated the robot position not accurate. I know that gmapping publish a tf transform from map to odom. Can I subscribe this transform and add it into my odometry or the transform from odom to baselink so that the position of my robot is more accurate?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202577/how-to-subcribe-tf-transform-from-map-to-odom-by-gmapping-into-odom-to-baselink?/) by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-02-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do not add anything manually. TF does that for you. Just use /map -> /base_link instead of /odom -> /base_link to get the robot position.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on 2015-03-05**:
Sorry for late reply, but my odometry transform is from odom to base_link. How could achieve directly from /amp ->/base_link

**Comment by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on 2015-03-05**:
my tf tree now is /map -> /odom -> base_link

is it what you means as below?
/map -> /base_link
/map -> /odom

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-03-05**:
tf tree looks good. Just use the map->base_link transform and you'll get your pose in the map.

**Comment by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on 2015-03-06**:
Currently I am getting my robot position in map by this way:

```
odom.pose.pose.position.x = x_move;
odom.pose.pose.position.y = y_move;
odom.pose.pose.position.z = 0.0;
odom.pose.pose.orientation = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(w_move);
```

**Comment by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on 2015-03-06**:
do you mean i should use this lookuptransform instead of odom to get my robot pose? something like this:

try {
listener.lookupTransform("map", "base_link", ros::Time(0), transform_in_map);
} catch(tf::TransformException &exception) {
ROS_ERROR("%s", exception.what());
}

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-03-06**:
Yes!                 .

**Comment by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on 2015-03-10**:
I have made this change:

```
odom.pose.pose.position.x = transform.getOrigin().x();
odom.pose.pose.position.y = transform.getOrigin().y();
odom.pose.pose.position.z = 0.0;
odom.pose.pose.orientation.z =tf::getYaw(transform.getRotation());;
```

**Comment by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on 2015-03-10**:
However, when the odom frames move, the robot remains stationary. The transform from map to odom published by gmapping and amcl is not send to the base_link

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-03-10**:
Do NOT change the odometry. The odometry is what it is. Run gmapping amcl or similar together with the odometry and use that output as your robot's accurate pose.

**Comment by [Zuhair95](https://answers.ros.org/users/87984/zuhair95/) on 2022-05-24**:
@mree
Did you solve the problem ? I mean how to get the gmapping estimated position ?
Thanks in advance .

**Comment by [Zuhair95](https://answers.ros.org/users/87984/zuhair95/) on 2022-05-24**:
Please, @dornhege
How to "use /map -> /base_link instead of /odom -> /base_link "